# Does magento provide EAV attribute import / export like product and customers?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to import attribute in Magento2 by programming but not getting success So there is any other way to create or update attribute via CSV or I will create all option manually.

Comment: I think you need to create this as a Magento customization, I would suggest you get a extension for it.